# Jackson FasterXML POJO to XML list

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using the FasterXML Jackson implementation to convert POJO's to XML output with the xml-databing package. I'm trying to achieve this output:

```
<MyRequest>
 <MySubRequest>4</MySubRequest>
 <MySubRequest>5</MySubRequest>
</MyRequest>
```

My classes:

```
public class MySubRequest {

@JacksonXmlText
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public MySubRequest(String id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

And:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class MyRequest {

private Collection<MySubRequest> MySubRequest;

public Collection<MySubRequest> getRequests() {
    return MySubRequest;
}

public void setRequests(Collection<MySubRequest> requests) {
    this.MySubRequest = requests;
}

}
```

I'm testing it with:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
MyRequest entity = new MyRequest();
Collection<MySubRequest> myIds = new ArrayList<>();
myIds.add(new MySubRequest("12"));
myIds.add(new MySubRequest("34"));
entity.setRequests(myIds);
mapper.writeValue(System.out, entity);
```

But the output is:

```
<MyRequest xmlns="">
 <requests>
  <requests>12</requests>
  <requests>34</requests>
 </requests>
</MyRequest>
```

Another thing I'd like to know is how to force the output to be case-sensitive i.e. uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation to ignore the wrapper. Just use it like :

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
class MyRequest {


    private Collection<MySubRequest> mySubRequest;

    public Collection<MySubRequest> getRequests() {
        return mySubRequest;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MySubRequest")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public void setRequests(Collection<MySubRequest> requests) {
        this.mySubRequest = requests;
    }

}
```

Here I have used `JacksonXmlProperty` annotation to use element name as "MySubRequest" in xml.